# MySQL index out of range with autoincrement

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I have a table "fuels" which has a row, which is a primary key, named "fuel_id" and that field is autoincrement. There are also 3 more rows which are typical strings. When I insert the data it throws an exception that the parameter index is out of range. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Just to be sure my insert string is:

```
"INSERT INTO fuels (fuel_id, fuel_type, price, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

Stack trace:

```
 [IndexOutOfRangeException: Parameter index is out of range.]
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection.CheckIndex(Int32 index) +117
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection.InternalGetParameter(Int32 index) +41
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) +41
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.SerializeParameter(MySqlParameterCollection parameters,       MySqlPacket packet, String parmName, Int32 parameterIndex) +138
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.InternalBindParameters(String sql, MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet) +710
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.BindParameters() +155
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.Execute() +33
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.PreparableStatement.Execute() +77
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +1925
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader() +37
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +164
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteDbCommand(DbCommand command, DataSourceOperation operation) +380
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteInsert(IDictionary values) +399
    System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Insert(IDictionary values, DataSourceViewOperationCallback callback) +81
    Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.PerformInsert(GridEditableItem editedItem, Boolean suppressRebind) +370
    Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.PerformInsert(GridEditableItem editedItem) +44
    Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.PerformInsert() +73
    Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs.ExecuteCommand(Object source) +6245
    Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +205
    System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
    Telerik.Web.UI.GridItem.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +71
    System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
    Telerik.Web.UI.GridEditFormItem.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +372
    System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +121
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +156
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +9643314
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

Comment: The number of parameters that are supplied with the insert command doesn't match the number of ? in your insert statement.

Comment: @rene There are four parameters and four ?

Comment: I would try this: `INSERT INTO fuels (fuel_type, price, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
INSERT INTO fuels (fuel_type, price, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

when a table coulmn is autoincriment don't include it in insert query, When you insert record by this query fuel_id column value is automatically inserted.